# How to resize docker container's cpu-share value dynamiclly?

Tags: docker, cgroups

I am using docker 1.11, I run a container like:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --cpu-shares 4 zeroboh/stress --cpu 2
```

I want to change cpu-shares's value while docker container keeps running. Is there any method to do so?

I tried to edit file `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/docker/[containerID]/cpu.shares` with VIM, but failed for "Fsync failed". It means I can't modify cgroup file directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [docker update](https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/reference/commandline/update/) is the way to go.
Could look like this (taken from referenced documentation)
`$ docker update --cpu-shares 512 abebf7571666`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

`echo 4 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/docker/${ContainerID}/cpu.shares`

instead of directly using vim.